# How to Disable dropdown option on basis of date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am creating a tool for booking in which if a user booked a time slot that option should be disabled for other users.
For example I have time slots 9:00 AM to 1:00 PM and 10:00 AM to 2:00 PM e.g in dropdown and also have a date selection field. If a user booked  24th oct 2018 date and choose 9:00 AM to 1:00 PM then that slot should be disable in dropdown so other user will not able to select that.

```
<div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="date" name="tool_date" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <h4>Service Timing Mon - Fri *</h4>

        <select class="form-control" name="tool_srvc_timing" style="height: 35px;">
          <?php
            include("db_connection.php");
            $query = "SELECT tool_time FROM main_tool";
            $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row['tool_time']; ?>">
              <?php echo $row['tool_time']; ?>
          </option>
          <?php } ?>
          <!-- <option value="">9:00 AM to 1:00 PM</option>
          <option value="">10:00 AM to 2:00 PM</option>
          <option value="">11:00 AM to 3:00 PM</option>
          <option value="">12:00 PM to 4:00 PM</option>
          <option value="">01:00 PM to 5:00 PM</option> -->
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

In above code I am using input type="date" for date selection and fetching time slots from database.
In database there are only two columns in table id and tool_time.
Please help me regarding this issue and what I need to do exactly to get the solution. I am simply emailing booking details to user and owner. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This will require constant checking of database for date and time that is already taken

Comment: how to do that? kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution.
1. i created two tables. One where i have time slots and then 2nd table to save booking details
2. i fetched time slots from first table to show in drop down through while loop and then again created second nested while loop to check if available in db then disable the option else not. Thank you for help and comments everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You want to disabled, booked time from dropdownlist

You need to check a condition in `php` that time is booked or not, if it is booked that apply `echo` to `disabled` inside `<option>` tag

```
<select class="form-control" name="tool_srvc_timing" style="height: 35px;">
    <?php
    include("db_connection.php");
    $query = "SELECT tool_time FROM main_tool";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <option <?php if($row['Booked_Column_Name']!="") echo "disabled"; ?> value="<?php echo $row['tool_time']; ?>">
        <?php echo $row['tool_time']; ?>
    </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

You need to replace `Booked_Column_Name` your database column name.

It will look something like this:

```html
<select class="form-control" name="tool_srvc_timing" style="height: 35px;">
    <option value="">9:00 AM to 1:00 PM</option>
    <option disabled value="">10:00 AM to 2:00 PM</option>
    <option value="">11:00 AM to 3:00 PM</option>
    <option disabled value="">12:00 PM to 4:00 PM</option>
    <option value="">01:00 PM to 5:00 PM</option>
</select>
```

Comment: how to link this with date?.User will select date first and then we will check if the time slot is already booked for that particular day then option will be disabled.

Comment: This is `php` server side coding, you need to pass selected date to server. Either apply it in `where` condition of sql query, or apply inside `<option>`. It depends on your coding structure.

Comment: i am still confused. i have tried your solution but i am unable to relate it with date. now i have created one more table for bookings and will insert booked slot there and fetch results accordingly.